# How do I perform an action on a subclassed UIView when tapped?

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, subclass, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have subclassed `UIView` and I want to be able to set a stroke colour around the view when it is tapped.

At the moment I have added a gesture recogniser to the view in my View Controller like so:

```
    CJGGameSquare* gameSquare = [[CJGGameSquare alloc] initWithSquareSize:_squareSize andSquareNumber:i andSquareName:[squareNames objectAtIndex:i]];
    [_mainBoard addSubview:gameSquare];

    CGRect gameSquareFrame = {
        xPosition,
        yPosition,
        _squareSize,
        _squareSize
    };

    [gameSquare setFrame:gameSquareFrame];

UIGestureRecognizer* singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(highlightSquare:)];
[gameSquare addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

I've also implemented the `highlightSquare` method as follows:

```
-(void)highlightSquare:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
{
    UIView* square = sender.view;
    square.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

This sets the background to red but I want instead to set a stroke colour or some other values that are unique to my `CJGGameSquare` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a subclass override these methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Then you can recognize when your `UIView` is touched an draw accordingly.

You could draw a border to view's layer or you could draw a rectangular path in the `drawRect:(NSRect *)` of your subclass.

For example:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
view.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
```